# Python GTK get selected value from the treeview

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

I am working on a mini GUI project , I am currently struggling to figure out how to get selected value from the list and then return that value to the main function so that I can use that value in somewhere else . Can someone help me please !!!!

```
    ####

    self.device_list_store = gtk.ListStore(str,str,str,str,str)
    for device in self.get_dev_list():
        self.device_list_store.append(list(device))

    device_list_treeview = gtk.TreeView(self.device_list_store)

    selected_row = device_list_treeview.get_selection()
    selected_row.connect("changed",self.item_selected)

    ####

    def item_selected(self,selection):
         model,row = selection.get_selected()
         if row is not None:
             selected_device = model[row][0]
```

at the moment ,the **item_selected** function is not returning anything , I want to return **selected_device** back to the main function so I can use it in other functions as well .

**EDIT:** I've edited code above to remove formatting errors @jcoppens

Comment: why not put `return selected_device` as last line of the `item_selected` function. And have a read of [some basic Python tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and [Gtk tutorials](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I tried return selected_device , and call the item_selected function in the main function , it doesn't work , the error msg says TypeError: item_selected() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given). I can understand I need to pass some arguments to that function , but the problem is I have no idea what parameters I need to use for that function , hopefully this makes sense to you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As you can see in the documentation](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeSelection.html#Gtk.TreeSelection.signals.changed), the `item_selected` function is called with one parameter, `tree_selection`. But if you define the function inside a class, it requires the `self` parameter too, which is normally added automatically. In your (confusing) example, there is no class defined, so I suspect the problem is your program which is incomplete.

Also, I suspect you don't want `device_list_treeview = gtk.T...` in the for loop:

```
for device in self.get_dev_list():
        self.device_list_store.append(list(device))
        device_list_treeview = gtk.TreeView(self.device_list_store)
```

And I suspect you want `selected_device = mod...` indented below the `if`:

```
 if row is not None:
 selected_device = model[row][0]
```

Please convert your example in a complete program, and formatted correctly.

BTW: `item_selected` is not a good name for the signal handler. It is also called if the item is unselected (which is why the signal is called 'changed')!

And **important**: Even though you should first read the [basic Python tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and [Gtk tutorials](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/), you should then consider using [lazka's excellent reference for all the Python APIs](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/). There's a link on the page to download it completely and have it at hand in your computer.

Comment: Thank you so much , the issue has been solved now . I will have a read of the training materials that you suggested to make sure I have all those basic stuff covered .

Comment: Great. I've edited your original question to remove the formatting problems.